# Corda opensource - Development network

Tags: corda

Can I launch a fully functional corda network for a static set of participants without configuring Trust root , NetworkMap or identityManager.

Does a dev setup require any other config apart from Nodes/Notaries?

Comment: [ask]..........

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Corda has the Network Bootstrapper tool which can be used to set-up a static test network for development purposes.

The tool is in fact integrated into the Corda Gradle plugin and it allows you to quickly deploy a test network using simple Gradle commands with some config defined in your Gradle build file.

All our samples also follow the approach of using the static test network.

Refer here to know how to run a Cordapp using test deployment: https://docs.corda.net/docs/corda-os/4.4/tutorial-cordapp.html